# Pycharm type hinting with abstract methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, abstract-class

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Shape(object):

    _metaclass_ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def calculate_area(self):
        """ Returns the area of the shape
        :return str: A string of the area. """
        pass

    def print_area(self):
        area = self.calculate_area()
        print("Area is " + area)
```

In this example all shapes calculate their area differently but all child classes have a common method that prints the current area. Pycharm complains about `area` in the last line, saying it has type `None` instead of `TypeVar('AnyStr', str, unicode)`. This makes sense, because `calculate_area` returns nothing. On the other hand, `calculate_area` is an abstract method and so it won't be called directly under `Shape`, it will be implemented differently by child classes. Obviously the return type of `calculate_area` can't be enforced on the Child classes, but shouldn't PyCharm hold off in telling me the type is wrong since `calculate_area` is abstract?

I'm wondering if Pycharm is at fault, or I am and this is not the way to implement this abstract class and I should try a different approach?

This is a minimal example. The code I'm working on has a main (non-abstract) method in the abstract class that calls many abstract methods. The main function works commonly across all Child classes but the abstract methods need to be overridden for the Child classes' specific purpose. As a result I have type hinting errors all over.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `calculate_area` in your example implicitly returns None. You could just "fix it" by returning an empty string. That would catch cases where a subclass just returns `super(Subclass, self).calculate_area()` in its `calculate_area`:

```
class Shape(object):

    _metaclass_ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def calculate_area(self):
        """ Returns the area of the shape
        :return str: A string of the area. """
        return ""

    def print_area(self):
        area = self.calculate_area()
        print("Area is " + area)
```

However it's not considered good style to add strings. So if you use `format` the problem won't exist in the first place because `format` can deal with any object that has a `__repr__` or `__str__` method (practically any object). So it would work even if `calculate_area` returns `None` or instead of a string it returns a number:

```
class Shape(object):

    _metaclass_ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def calculate_area(self):
        """ Returns the area of the shape
        :return str: A string of the area. """
        pass

    def print_area(self):
        area = self.calculate_area()
        print("Area is {}".format(area))
```